# What is the Union datatype from the Error Message?

Tags: python

I received an error saying I need to pass Union datatype as the parameter. Checking PEP there is no saying about union datatype. Am I missing something?

`Error Message: type of val must be Union[ float, numpy.floating, numpy.integer]`

What I have tried is just parsing the error message to understand the require data structure

Comment: I believe it means that `val` needs to be one of the listed data types. `val` can be a `float`, `np.float`, or `np.interger`. What currently is the data type of `val`?

Comment: I know why now. It is `numpy.ndarray`. I should access the array to the value. something akin to `arr[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Union](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union) is a data type for type hinting when a variable must be one of the listed types.

This means that `Union[float, numpy.floating, numpy.integer]` suggests that the type must be either: `float`, `numpy.floating`, or `numpy.integer`.

The reason you are getting this error message means that you are passing a variable that isn't of one of those types. To fix this error message, your parameter - `val` - must be one of those data types.